# How do you use Frame Shift Drive to travel to the destination on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, elite-dangerous

This is specific to the preview version of Elite: Dangerous on Xbox One - on PC this appears to be <kbd>J</kbd>, but obviously that doesn't apply to the Xbox controller.

In one of the training missions you hyperspace to the next system and then use your Frame Shift Drive (FSD) to travel to a nearby station.

However, once you get there you don't seem to be able to get out of FSD, you just zoom around the destination. If you use the <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to exit you drop out wherever you are - many minutes or hours away at normal speeds.

When you are close to the station and travelling below C you seem to get a prompt at the bottom of the screen `SAFE DISENGAGE READY`, but there's no indication or help in game as to how you action that. There doesn't appear to be a binding in any of the controls or options indicating how you carry out a safe disengage (or even what a safe disengage is).

How do I action that prompt?

Comment: It should be the same button to disengage FSD as it is to engage it.

Comment: @Unionhawk On xbone you hold `A`, which brings up a sub menu, then press `up` on the D-pad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're approaching the station or wherever you want to leave FSD make sure your speed and distance markers on the scales at the bottom left of the screen are roughly aligned. Thus, as you approach the target, your speed and distance markers fall together. Once both are in the blue section of the scale, you should get the 'safe to disengage' warning. As soon as you do, hit the A button and D pad up. It's the same as the engage super cruise engage button. You should then emerge close to your target.  Now have you got any idea how on earth you attack another ship when you're in super cruise????

Comment: Cheers - part of the trick is to approach at the right speed, and part is that you don't have to wait for the hold `A` menu to appear, you can just tap `A` + `Up` together quickly.

Comment: @paul - you cannot attack a ship in Supercruise, but you can buy and equip an FSD Interdictor device, assign it to a weapon group, activate that weapon group, lock on to an enemy ship in Supercruise and then use your weapon control (primary or secondary as appropriate) to pull the ship into normal space, then you can attack them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't specifically say for the Xbox version as I don't have access to it, but from your description it sounds like you are not trying to drop out at the correct time.  If A + Up drops you out of Supercruise at any time, then this should be the same control to drop you out when the Safe Disengage message is displayed.  On the PC it is the same control at either time (as it is the same action, the only difference being the location you drop out to).

Comment: On Xbox `A` pops a sub menu, then you press `up` on the d-pad to enter FSD. When you try to do that to exit the `SAFE DISENGAGE READY` prompt disappears. Shouldn't there be a single thing to press?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm going by how the PC version works.  I'd figured that since the PC version can be operated with an Xbox controller, the Xbox controls would work the same way as the PC version does.  Hopefully someone with the Xbox version will be able to answer your question better than I have been able to.